# Segue to a view controller that's within a tabbar and navbar

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

1 tabbarcontroller connected to 3 navigation controllers. each navigation controller is connected to a view controller. in #3 a button segues modally to a view controller. i dont want the segue to be "push". is there anyway i can create a button in that view controller that segues back to #3?

I want a button in "randomviewcontroller" to perform a segue to "viewcontroller3" that is within a navigation controller and tabbarcontroller. "viewcontroller3" is the third tabbarbutton view.

so:

randomviewcontroller to perform segue to

TabBarController -(relationshipsegue)-> NavigationController -(rootview controllersegue)-> viewcontroller3

Example: a login view controller. you press login button, and it segues to the third tabbar button view (view that you see if you tap third icon on tabbar). third tabbar button is connected to a navigation controller that is rootview of a view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I quite understand your question (and I don't see why you would have a login view controller in one of your tabs, most likely it would be in a view controller of its own).

Try connecting the button to the following code (assuming that the button is in the login tab)

```
-(IBAction) login:(id)sender {
     [self.tabBar setSelectedItem:[self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2]];
}
```

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 3):

If the view controllers in the `tabbarviewcontrollers.viewcontrollers` array are all navigation controllers and you just want to programmatically switch tabs and show the root view controller of that navigation controller, then all you should need is to switch to the index of the tab you want to select:

```
tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2 //or whatever index you want
```

Comment: i only want that segue to goto tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2. ive been messing around with "if segue.identifier == "customtopack"". in the tabbarviewcontroller but havent been able to get it to work

Comment: I don't believe you should use a segue at all.  In your example the user presses a login button.  Put the above code in the login method, no need to use a segue.

Comment: with that solution any view controller that segues to the tab bar will goto tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2

Comment: Sorry, " any view controller that segues to the tab bar " really doesn't make much sense to me.  I think there might be more context to your project then what you're asking in the question.

Comment: sorry im new to coding so its hard to explain for me. 1 tabbarcontroller connected to 3 navigation controllers. each navigation controller is connected to a view controller. in #3 a button segues modally to a view controller. i dont want the segue to be "push". is there anyway i can create a button in that view controller that segues back to #3?